# How can I receive message by Low Energy Bluetooth when the application is not running?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I make an application by CoreBluetooth that can receive data from other BLE device.

I want to get a notification when I receive a new msg from BLE device.

But Apple doesn't allow any application runs in background.

And APNS needs the internet. But the msg is from bluetooth.

Is there any good solutions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPS,Audio and Bluetooth Low Energy are allowed in the background.
you must set "requires background service" something in Xcode for your project.
for some GPS apps I use internet as well in the background.